# Index is out of bounds when using for loop

Tags: python, arrays

I want to create a new array with specific elements of the original array.
I created a minimal example and there it works what I want to achieve, but on the actual data it doesn't and I can't figure out the essential difference.

First the minimal example:
I want to get the numbers of every row that stand under the letters A-C and save it in the array B_feat.

```
    import numpy as np
    years  = 5 #A-E
    yearsf = 3 #A-C

    B_new =(['0','A','B','C','D','E','A','B','C','D','E'],
            ['X','2','3','3','3','4','6','5','4','3','4'],
            ['Y','3','4','6','7','3','2','4','7','9','8'],
            ['Z','3','4','6','3','4','6','9','1','4','7']) 

    B_feat = np.zeros((3,2*yearsf))     

    i=0
    for row in B_feat:
        j=0    
        k=0
        for element in row:
            B_feat[i][j:int(j+yearsf)]=B_new[i+1][k+1:int(k+yearsf+1)]
            j+=yearsf
            k+=years
        i+=1        

    print B_feat
```

and I receive

```
[[ 2.  3.  3.  6.  5.  4.]
 [ 3.  4.  6.  2.  4.  7.]
 [ 3.  4.  6.  6.  9.  1.]]
```

Now with the actual data I have:

```
    years  = 9
    yearsf = 4
    np.shape(B_new)  = (244, 181)
    np.shape(B_feat) = (243, 76)
```

I want to have a new array B_feat that ignores the first row and column of B_new, then skips 9 columns and starts "extracting" always the first 4 out of the next 9  row elements.

```
    import numpy as np
    i=0
    for row in B_feat:
        j=0    
        k=0
        for element in row:
            B_feat[i][j:int(j+yearsf)]=B_new[i+1][int(k+1+years):int(k+years+yearsf+1)]
            j+=yearsf
            k+=years

        i+=1
```

When running the code, I receive the following error:

```
    IndexError: index 80 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 76
```

I don't really understand this error since I thought axis 0 is down the rows (where I have 243 for B_feat) and I could't figure out where the index goes up to 80.

As I'm  new to python and this forum, please let me know if I can improve my question or anything is unclearly stated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, you are getting out of range as the error suggest,
and this is also true for the minimal example that seems to work.
I do not know why it works for the minimal example in the first place.

Detailled answer:
In the minimal example, `B_new`has `6` columns indexed from `0` to `5`.
Your internal loop iterate over the number of columns of `B_new`. 
And for each iteration, it increments `j` by `yearsf` which is `3`.
At the third iteration, `j` is `6` wich is larger than the max index `5`.
You have the exact same issue with the index `k`.

Suggestion:
The number of iteration in your internal loop must be the number of group
of columns to process, `2` in your minimal example. By group of column, I
simply mean a set of columns below 'A-C'.
Your loops can be turned into something like this:

```
i=0
for row in B_feat:
    for j,k in zip( range(0,B_feat.shape[1], yearsf),
    range(1,B_new.shape[1], years)):
        print 'i = ', i, ', j = ', j, ', k = ', k
        B_feat[i][j:int(j+yearsf)]=B_new[i+1][k:int(k+yearsf)]
    i+=1
```

Notice that I remove the `+1` in the slice of `B_new` and set `k`
to start at `1`
And I will advise you to turn the external loop into something like
`for i in range(B_feat.shape[0])` and remove the statement `i+=1`

Comment: Great, I adjusted the code in the following way and it worked out! Thanks a lot for your help! Unfortunately I can't post the code here in  a nice format, but I also added the external loop;)

Comment: @Dave, there is absolutely no need to post your final code here. You solved your problem and accepted an answer to help those whose have similar problem in the future.